# Cannot get hover to work on my dummy links in my CodePen Project

Tags: html, css

I cannot get hover to work on the dummy links in my CodePen. The cursor won’t even change to the hand icon. I am referring to the navigation bar, the dummy links do not work properly. Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrlondon/project/live/AVpmPm/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("wallpaper2.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  background: pink;
  height: 1000px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.lastlist {
  padding-right: 65px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #f0c330;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <nav>
      <h1>Daniel Savva</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">  Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">  Gallery</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">  About</a> </li>
        <li class="lastlist"> <a href="#">  Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `<h1>` overlaps all links. Use `display: inline-block` on the `h1` for example. Use the [inspector in your dev tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your h1 tag is overlapping the ul tag

Solution is to add **position:relative** to your ul tag :)

Because Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM and elements with non-static positioning ( relative ,absolute ..)  will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning.

h1 : position:relative

ul : default static position

Adding position:relative will force your ul element to be on TOP.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("wallpaper2.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  background: pink;
  height: 1000px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
position : relative ;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.lastlist {
  padding-right: 65px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #f0c330;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <nav>
      <h1>Daniel Savva</h1>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">  Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">  Gallery</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">  About</a> </li>
        <li class="lastlist"> <a href="#">  Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</body>

</html>
```